# A0 poster error code

Tags: errors, posters

I submit to the wisdom of forumers this request.
I'm very disturbed by this error code:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.

    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
    ...                                              

l.51
```

And as suggest by [thorsten](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3240/thorsten)  and [Daniel E. Shub](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10038/daniel-e-shub) there is the minimal code source with another error:

```
    ! LaTeX Error: File `rsda2012' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.278 \end{minipage}}

? x
```

A minimal working example might be:

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0b,final,a4resizeable]{a0poster}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage[dvips]{color}

    \begin{document}
     \begin{poster}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Header
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}

\begin{pcolumn}{0.98}
\pbox{0.95\textwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.3,linecolor=lightblue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=whiteblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{\begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.1\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=8cm]{univ}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
%%% Titre
\begin{minipage}[c][9cm][c]{0.78\textwidth}
\begin{center}
{\sc \Huge \blue
    Equation différentielle dirigée par un mouvement Brownien fractionnaire}\\[10mm]
    {\Large LABAIR Abdelkader \\[7.5mm]
   Laboratoire de Mathématiques, Université Djillali Liabes, Sidi Bel Abbes.}
  \end{center}
\begin{flushright}
   \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=8cm]{rsda2012}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}
\end{pcolumn}
\end{center}
\end{poster}
    \end{document}
```

Sincerely

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You have asked 8 questions and **accepted no answers**. I *strongly* suggest that you look over your past questions and see if any answers may be accepted.

Comment: Accepting with Mark S. Everitt and Thorsten. You may add `\PassOptionsToPackage{options}{color}` before `\documentclass{article}` and remove `\usepackage{color}` from your preamble.

Comment: Adding to the other comments, you haven't voted a single time. I'm assuming you just don't know how some things on this site work, as you wouldn't have any reason to be mean or the like. **Please do make sure to read the [faq]**, they tell you how you'll have more success with tex.sx.

Comment: For Mark S. Everitt, thanks for letting me know.  But Mr. Know that I was satisfied with the all answers  that I express my thanks.

Comment: @Labaïr: I restate that you should mark answers as correct when they are. As it is, you are abusing stack exchange. I'm sure that if Harish Kumar puts his answer that you will mark it as correct. In addition, if you do not add a minimal working example to the question **it will be closed**, since we cannot tell what the question is.

Comment: @Labaïr: This is by no means a minimal working example. Please also have a look at the link Thorsten pointed you to.

Comment: There is *no* need to load the color package nor, of course epsfig. By omitting them the file compiles without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

In an effort to help Labair get an answer, I think his MWE can be significantly reduced. I can recreate the error with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The simple solution to resolve the error appears to be to load `color` before `pstricks`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Avoiding the `[dvips]` option is surely best.

Comment: And the [color](http://ctan.org/pkg/color) package isn't needed at all since [PSTricks](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) itself loads [xcolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor).

Comment: @ThorstenDonig @egreg, I saw the Labair posted a "MWE" and thought I would try and help out. I think the load order is easier to understand than dependencies and what the `dvips` option does or even why you might want `\PassOptionsToPackage`.